# select an element which is inside title tag with Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some html code like this.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com.pk" id="goog" title="<table width='20%' border='1'> <tr> <td>ABC</td>    <td>DEF</td>  </tr></table>"> Go to Google </a>
```

I want to call alert function when user will hover to table td tag which is inside to Table and table is inside of  tag.

Is it possible with Jquery?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have never seen anyone do anything like this. HTML inside title tag which you want to bind events to? You need to seriously rethink your structure.

Comment: I am using Poshy Tip which allows me to add html in Tool tip. I've added a table in tooltip. Its working very well. But I want to select different rows of this table which is inside of this tooltip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML is not allowed within the title attribute.

Have a look at this, as one of many solutions how to achive CSS tooltips:

http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-only-tooltips/

Comment: I am using Poshy Tip which allows me to add html in Tool tip. I've added a table in tooltip. Its working very well. But I want to select different rows of this table which is inside of this tooltip.

Comment: I'm quite sure Poshy will pull the table out of the alt tag and place it in a new DOM element. Use Firebug, or something similar to find out what this new DOM element looks like. This will be the one you like to access with JQuery.

Comment: Hi Jochen!

Here is the link where you can see my code

http://doonella.com/demo/demo.html

Thanks
Shahid

Comment: Your table is inside div.tip-yellow. So $("div.tip-yellow") should work for selecting the tables container

Comment: I've tried this code.

$("div.tip-yellow").click(function(){
                   alert('table found');
                });

When I click on tip then it doesn't alert. What is wrong there